# Чем плох iframe (в контексте альтернативы rest api)?

Tags: iframe, rest

Я создаю приложение, которое будет интегрироваться с сайтом сторонней компании. Мне нужно было получить апи от сайта (получить список пользователей, роли и т.д.). Разработчик из той компании, где сайт, предложил все делать через iframe.

И я банально не могу привести доказательство, чем iframe хуже, чем, например, rest api.

Помогите с доводами или развейте мой мысль, что iframe хуже чем api.

P.S. Плюсы, названные другим разработчиком, только в скорости разработки, типа если что я вызову через parent твои функции и все будет уже работать.

**Обновление**

Я привык, что если от внешнего сервиса нужно получить или передать какую-то информацию, то используется один из видов апи (SOAP, REST и т.д.)
А тут мне предлагают: "давай ты не будешь получать от нас список пользователей, а просто внедришь iframe на страницу, где будет список пользователей". Мини-задача у меня стоит: вывести список пользователей, и при клике на пользователя я могу написать ему сообщение (а-ля месенжер). А теперь мне нужно внедрить внешний сайт в какой-то див, отобразиться список пользователей, а при клике на пользователя выводиться `parent.createMessage()`.
Сейчас это решит поставленную задачу, но я не вижу перспектив такого подхода, кроме как потом добавится логика (например, особо фильтровать этот список), и придется все равно все переделывать на апи.
(Хотел добавить, что я всегда был бэкендом, а тут нужно поработать на фронте, и я последний раз слышал о iframe лет 8 назад, и только плохое.)

Comment: так если у вас нет доводов, то почему же вы не хотите принять предлагаемый вам вариант?

Comment: все мои доводы это (WTF iframe), вот поэтому решил спросить у вас, может есть лучшие слова. Ладно честно мой главный довод почему я не хочу, потому что считаю неверным использоваться iframe для передачи данных между сайтами. Я также когда писал приложение для facebook, и там был iframe, но я понимал что это нужно для кросбраузерности, в моей же варианте описываеться админская чать, тоесть кросбраузерность ненужна, а нужно стандартное - расширяемое поведение

Comment: > не хочу, потому что считаю неверным использоваться iframe для передачи данных между сайтами

ну у вас же должны быть какиие-то основания так считать, не так ли? Не то что бы я хочу вас убедить использовать iframe (у него есть и достоинства и недостатки), однако же любопытно было бы узнать ваши причины так думать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST api будет лучше от iframe по следующим причинам:

1. Безопасность (в данном сравнении это самое главное).
2. Масштабируемость системы.
3. Гибкость системы, в любой момент можно выпустить новую версию api, с измененными интерфейсами.
4. Нагрузка на сервер будет меньше при использовании REST API.

На дворе 2014 год, iframe уже давно ушел в тень. А REST API все чаще и чаще используется для получения/редактирования информация из внешней системы.

Тут вопрос в том: "Почему программист не хочет реализовывать обмен данными через REST api?".
Тут уже становится вопрос о его профессиональном уровне.

А по поводу скорости разработки, то реализовать REST api можно куда быстрее, чем iframe. Возможно, программист просто не знаком с принципами и реализацией REST API, поэтому и пропагандирует свой, известный ему, метод.

Comment: 1. В чем отличие безопасности между
 - site_2.com вызывает через ajax site_1.com/api/users/filter/12
 - на сайте site_2 есть iframe site_1 который вызывает parent.api.putUsers([1,2,3])

Comment: после того как вы написали такой ответ, у вас осталось всего одно очко уважения, поэтому подозреваю что ваш ответ не лучший :)

Answer (score 2):

Я лично не вижу ничего общего между `iframe` и `rest api`, поэтому я не знаю, как их можно сравнить.

Если будет известно больше фактов, из-за которых ваш программист решил, что iframe эффективней, чем rest api, то я, возможно, дополню ответ.

А так по вопросу пару ссылок:

[**Фрейм_(HTML)**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Фрейм_(HTML)) и [**REST Api**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)

Comment: связь между iframe и rest api в том что их можно оба использовать для RPC